# Add collection of elements base class arraylist?

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I am using two class one is variablesclass and another one is arraylist test class. I have add multiple values in variablesclass. How to add collection of elements base class arraylist?

```
public class VariablesClass {

    private ArrayList<Integer> ids;
    private ArrayList<String> names;


    public ArrayList<Integer> getIds() {
        return ids;
    }
    public void setIds(ArrayList<Integer> ids) {
        this.ids = ids;
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getNames() {
        return names;
    }
    public void setNames(ArrayList<String> names) {
        this.names = names;
    }

}
```

Main class

```
public class ArraylistTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        VariablesClass varClass = null;
        try{
            varClass=new VariablesClass();

            varClass.setIds(11);
            varClass.getIds().add(12);
            varClass.getIds().add(13);
            varClass.getIds().add(14);
            varClass.getIds().add(15);
            varClass.getNames().add("karthick");
            varClass.getNames().add("Ramana");
            varClass.getNames().add("Priya");
            varClass.getNames().add("Madhu");
            varClass.getNames().add("Ammu");

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.getLocalizedMessage();
        }


        for(int is: varClass.getIds()){
            System.out.println("Integer Previous Class :"+is);
        }

    }

}
```

How to use get/set of this class.  Here i am getting null pointer exception how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

You can do what @sanket suggested, or then use your current class like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  VariablesClass varClass = null;

  try {
    varClass = new VariablesClass();
    ArrayList<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

    ids.add(11);
    ids.add(12);
    ids.add(13);
    ids.add(14);
    ids.add(15);

    varClass.setIds(ids);

    names.add("karthick");
    names.add("Ramana");
    names.add("Priya");
    names.add("Madhu");
    names.add("Ammu");

    varClass.setNames(names);
  } catch(Exception e) {
    e.getLocalizedMessage();
  }

  for(int is: varClass.getIds()){
    System.out.println("Integer Previous Class :"+is);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The above code will give you a null pointer. Reason: Your array lists are not initialized.

You need to initialize them in the constructor of your class.

Further, it best if you define more methods, other than getter and setter that will add data to the array list.

```
public class VariablesClass {


private ArrayList<Integer> ids;
private ArrayList<String> names;


 public VariablesClass() {
       ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       names = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

public ArrayList<Integer> getIds() {
    return ids;
}
public void setIds(ArrayList<Integer> ids) {
    this.ids = ids;
}
public ArrayList<String> getNames() {
    return names;
}
public void setNames(ArrayList<String> names) {
    this.names = names;
}

public void addName(String name)
{
    this.names.add(name);
}

public void addId(Integer id)
{
    this.ids.add(id);
}
```

}

Call the method addName as many times as you need !

Comment: multiple values add. because constructor has initialize single values only. how to add multiple values.

Comment: @KarthikeyanKarthik can you clarify "multiple values add" and "how to add multiple values"? do you want to put all of the add calls into a single statement?